# Datapicker cannot display results

Tags: jquery

I want to display only the date that i choose from datapicker, but when i click a date it does not display nothing:
This is my datapicker function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy' }).val();
        var date = new Date();
        from.setDate(from.getDate());
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", date);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
});
var date = new Date();
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", date);
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='datepicker'/>
```

*Note: Don't use document.ready twice.  `$(function () {` is short form of  `document.ready`.*